# How to delete picture / shape from excel sheet to avoid the error xlwings.ShapeAlreadyExists

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions, xlwings

I am sending a matplotlib chart into excel as a picture and giving it a name.

However, if the code is run again, the picture would not be updated and the following error is raised:
xlwings.ShapeAlreadyExists

here is a snippet of the code:

```
caller.sheet.pictures.add(a, 
                         top=caller.offset(row_offset=1).top, 
                         left=caller.left,
                         name="memberss", update=False)
```

I realise that if I change update to True, this would work but the shape would retain its dimensions and not be updated.

What I want to do is to actually delete the existing shape and insert a new one in its place.

Is there a Pictures.delete attribute which takes the name of the shape and delete it?

I see there is Picture.delete but I dont seem to get it to work

[Picture.delete](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lfFhx.png)

https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.main.Pictures.add

Comment: Yes, just below where you were looking in the documentation is "Picture", and "delete" is one of the first, [here](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/api.html#xlwings.Picture.delete).

Answer (score 0):

As per the [documentation](https://docs.xlwings.org/en/stable/matplotlib.html):
`If you set update=True, you can resize and position the plot on Excel: subsequent calls to pictures.add() with the same name ('MyPlot') will update the picture without changing its position or size.`
So if you want to update the picture just place the argument `update=True`.
and your code would be like this:

```
caller.sheet.pictures.add(a, 
                         name="my plot name"
                         update=True,
                         top=caller.offset(row_offset=1).top, 
                         left=caller.left,
                         name="memberss", update=False)
```